# Combine multiple array of object with diffrent key

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have 2 array of object with diffrent key each other, i want to combine those array become 1 array,

Array of object 1

```
0:{materi: "materi1"}
1:{materi: "materi2"}
2:{materi: "materi3"}
3:{materi: "materi4"}
```

Array of object 2

```
0:{colour: "#FFEBCD"}
1:{colour: "#8A2BE2"}
2:{colour: "#DEB887"}
3:{colour: "#5F9EA0"}
```

what i have done is here push, concat but doesnt give me the output that i want to

```
console.log(mapped, 'mapped') 
console.log(color, 'color')
//console.log(mapped.push(color))
//console.log(mapped.push.apply(mapped, color))
// console.log(mapped.concat(color))
```

this is the output that i want

```
[{
  "color": '#E9967A',
  "materi": "Laurie Henderson"
},
{
  "color": '#8B0000',
  "materi": "Toni Ferrell"
},
{
  "color": '#9932CC',
  "materi": "Christi Summers"
},
{
  "color": '#FF8C00',
  "materi": "Adams Gray"
},
{
  "color": '#556B2F',
  "materi": "Maricela Bernard"
}]
```

Comment: Your input and output have different values. Also have you tried anything?

Comment: @Rajesh sorry the output just only for example that i want to so ignore the values. i tried mapped, push and concat but doesn't give me the result that i want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array1 = [{materi: "materi1"},
              {materi: "materi2"},
              {materi: "materi3"},
              {materi: "materi4"}];
var array2 = [{colour: "#FFEBCD"},
              {colour: "#8A2BE2"},
              {colour: "#DEB887"},
              {colour: "#5F9EA0"}];
var newArray = array1.map(function(val, ind){
    return {
        materi:val.materi,
        colour:array2[ind].colour
    }
})
```

Comment: wow your so fast edit the answer, it give me knowledge about data in javasacript

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new array with combination of the properties, they cannot automatically merge into new objects.

One way to do that is:

```
var arr1 = [{colour: "#FFEBCD"}], arr2 = [{materi: "materi1"}]; // your arrays

var combined = arr1.map(function(element, index){
    return {
        color: element.color,
        materi: arr2[index].materi
    }
})
```

Without further explanation on how you want the properties to be merged into new objects I think that's the best answer that can be given.

Also it is a bit dangerous as we cannot be sure that both arrays have the same length - so that needs to be handled somehow as well.

Comment: and yes those array doesn't have same length before combine both already cut one of them has same length, 

cause one array i set for 20 and the other dynamic from API, thanks or correction

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` to merge two array. Use value from the first array and using the index to get the value from the second array.

```js
const materials = [{materi: "materi1"},{materi: "materi2"},{materi: "materi3"},{materi: "materi4"}],
      colors = [{colour: "#FFEBCD"},{colour: "#8A2BE2"},{colour: "#DEB887"},{colour: "#5F9EA0"}];
      
const result = materials.map(({materi}, index) => ({'color' : colors[index].colour, materi}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Its really going to be difficult for OP to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge each pair together.

```js
var materials = [{materi: "materi1"},{materi: "materi2"},{materi: "materi3"},{materi: "materi4"}];
var colors = [{colour: "#FFEBCD"},{colour: "#8A2BE2"},{colour: "#DEB887"},{colour: "#5F9EA0"}];

var merged = materials.map(function(m, i) {
  return Object.assign({}, m, colors[i]);
})

console.log(merged)
```

Or using es6:

```js
let materials = [{materi: "materi1"},{materi: "materi2"},{materi: "materi3"},{materi: "materi4"}];
let colors = [{colour: "#FFEBCD"},{colour: "#8A2BE2"},{colour: "#DEB887"},{colour: "#5F9EA0"}];

let merged = materials.map((m, i) => Object.assign({}, m, colors[i]))

console.log(merged)
```